# Getting org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException though it works fine sql server?

Tags: java, hibernate

i have below code snippet. It throws the exception at **line 3**  but query works fine managemnt studio(sql server 2005)

```
String query = "select * from user where userId=" + profileId
    + " and spaceName='" + spaceName + "'";

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

List<PersonDetailsData> personDetailsData = new ArrayList<PersonDetailsData>(
    session.createQuery(query).list()); //line 3
```

Here is the exception

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near
>   line 1, column 8 [select * from user where userId=216 and
>   spaceName='DIG']

I am not able to figure out  what's the problem with query when it is running fine in management sudio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's native query, not hql. 
If you have mapped table field to class fields you need

```
session.createSQLQuery(query, PersonDetailsData.class).list();
```

or create hql type query -

```
select p from PersonDetailData p where p.userId = :userId and p.spaceName =:spaceName
```

and use parameters in query, not direct values.

Comment: Thanks DainusI have one more query i.e if this query does not return any data, will query.list will be null or not null. If it is not null then if i do personDetailsData.get(0) will it be null or not null. (Because i have to to do some operations based on null or not null values)

Comment: If you call for list() it should not return null, but there's a special method for single object "getSingleResult()", if I good remember it throws exception when there is no result.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using sql query so you have to create a sql query such as

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS").list();
```

see the source [source](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querysql.html)